# How to make a natural-looking list?

Tags: c#, linq, list, join

By natural-looking, what I mean is this:

> item1, item2, item3 and item4.

I know that you can just do a comma-separated list with `string.Join`, like

> item1, item2, item3, item4

but how can you make this sort of list? I've got a rudimentary solution:

```
int countMinusTwo = theEnumerable.Count() - 2;
string.Join(",", theEnumerable.Take(countMinusTwo)) + "and " 
    + theEnumerable.Skip(countMinusTwo).First();
```

but I'm pretty sure there's a better (as in more efficient) way to do it. Anyone? Thanks.

Comment: so what would be output look like ?

Comment: @Tigran The output's at the top. First quote-block. =)

Comment: Wouldn't your code produce `"item1, item2 and item3."`?

Comment: @J.Steen More efficient? Seems like O(2n) to me.

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but the punctuation in the OP's natural-looking list is incorrect. There should be a comma also after the penultimate item: `item1, item2, item3, and item4`. Robert Graves in The Reader Over Your Shoulder gives the example of someone dividing his wealth in a last will and testament, among the following individuals (paraphrasing since memory fails):  "Tom, Dick and Harry".  Tom gets half.  "Tom, Dick, and Harry". They each get a third.

Comment: @Tim - the use of the [oxford comma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma) is open for debate.

Comment: The definition of "oxford/harvard comma" there is crude and unnecessarily complicated. `...a comma placed immediately before the coordinating conjunction (usually and, or, or nor) in a series of three or more terms`. That definition could be simplified, indeed eliminated as otiose, simply by defining "comma" correctly: A punctuation mark between the items in a list that unambiguously shows which elements are discrete monads and which are to be considered as associated items within the list, for example: `pop, rap, hip-hop, emo, rock and roll, punk, rhythm and blues, gospel, and classical`

Comment: Is all this helping to resolve the question?

Comment: @ncourcy84: Yes, it goes the issue of "natural looking". We're defining "natural" :-)

Comment: @Tim - Well, what is or isn't "natural" in this case is very subjective. Even while I agree, a comma like that would be *logical*, "natural" is what each individual is most used to. So without context, not using it can't simply be called "incorrect".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should calculate the size once and store it in a variable. Otherwise the query(if it's no a collection) will be executed everytime. Also, `Last` is more readable if you want the last item.

```
string result;
int count = items.Count();
if(count <= 1)
    result = string.Join("", items);
else
{
    result = string.Format("{0} and {1}"
        , string.Join(", ", items.Take(counter - 1))
        , items.Last());
}
```

If readability is less important and the sequence could be quite large:

```
var builder = new StringBuilder();
int count = items.Count();
int pos = 0;
foreach (var item in items)
{
    pos++;
    bool isLast = pos == count;
    bool nextIsLast = pos == count -1;
    if (isLast)
        builder.Append(item);
    else if(nextIsLast)
        builder.Append(item).Append(" and ");
    else
        builder.Append(item).Append(", ");
}
string result = builder.ToString();
```

Comment: I'd classify that as "better" as it's easier to read & as efficient as it's going to get

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance: If you make an extension you could add an optional parameter for the suffix("and", "or" etc.).

Answer (score 1):

I would have worked with a string.

Let's say you have :

```
string items = "item1, item2, item3, item4";
```

Then you could do :

```
int lastIndexOf = items.LastIndexOf(",");
items = items.Remove(lastIndexOf);
items = items.Insert(lastIndexOf, " and");
```

Comment: what if he has `"item1"` only

Comment: lastIndexOf will return -1. Handle it.

Comment: Quick. Someone calculate the complexity! ;)